# Connection refused when trying to create graph in JanusGraph-Docker

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, cassandra, gremlin, janusgraph

I'm using the JanusGraph-Docker images (https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph-docker) to set up JanusGraph in Docker. When I used JanusGraph without docker everything worked fine for me, but now I've ran into some issues:

I've used the following command to set up janusgraph with Cassandra+Elasticsearch:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-cql-es.yml up
```

This starts all the required containers, which I double checked with:

```
docker ps
```

Now I want to connect to Janusgraph via Gremlin console using:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-cql-es.yml run --rm -e GREMLIN_REMOTE_HOSTS=janusgraph janusgraph ./bin/gremlin.sh
```

This starts the gremlin console and I configure the remote with:

```
:remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml
:remote console
```

Which works fine aswell. After that I try to create a new graph, which fails with:

```
graph = JanusGraphFactory.open('conf/janusgraph-cassandra-es.properties')
```

This gives me the following message:

> Connection refused (Connection refused)

Full Stack Trace:

> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
>       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
>       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>       at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>       at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
>       at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:182)
>       at org.apache.thrift.transport.TFramedTransport.open(TFramedTransport.java:81)
>       at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.thriftpool.CTConnectionFactory.makeRawConnection(CTConnectionFactory.java:110)
>       at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.thriftpool.CTConnectionFactory.makeObject(CTConnectionFactory.java:74)
>       at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.thriftpool.CTConnectionFactory.makeObject(CTConnectionFactory.java:43)
>       at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1220)
>       at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftStoreManager.getCassandraPartitioner(CassandraThriftStoreManager.java:215)
>       at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftStoreManager.(CassandraThriftStoreManager.java:197)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>       at org.janusgraph.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:58)
>       at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend.getImplementationClass(Backend.java:440)
>       at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend.getStorageManager(Backend.java:411)
>       at org.janusgraph.graphdb.configuration.builder.GraphDatabaseConfigurationBuilder.build(GraphDatabaseConfigurationBuilder.java:50)
>       at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:161)
>       at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:132)
>       at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:79)
>       at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory$open.call(Unknown Source)
>       at Script4.run(Script4.groovy:1)
>       at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.jsr223.GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.eval(GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.java:674)
>       at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.jsr223.GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.eval(GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.java:376)
>       at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:233)
>       at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.engine.GremlinExecutor.lambda$eval$0(GremlinExecutor.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

I can run queries such as the following since janusgraph server seems to pre-deploy a graph with a traversal object:

```
g.addV('user').property('username','exampleUserName')
```

But when I'm trying to connect from python gremlin with:

```
graph = Graph()
g = graph.traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection('ws://0.0.0.0:8182/gremlin','g'))
```

I get the same error, any help?

Comment: Did you actually specify `0.0.0.0` as the IP of the host in gremlin-python? It should of course be the IP address under which the JanusGraph container can be reached.

Comment: If i check on which IPs and Ports my containers are running it says that the janusgraph container is running on `0.0.0.0:8182->8182/tcp` in gremlin-python specifying the ip like `ws://0.0.0.0:8182/gremlin` in the `DriverRemoteConnection` should be enough, right?

Comment: Did you ever manage to fix this? I ran into the same problem and found that the cause was that the server could not connect to the elasticsearch service. The thing is that I have no idea how to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Note that when your server **listens** on `0.0.0.0`, that means it will be accessible from machines other than the one that it's running on. The alternative of listening on `127.0.0.1` means it will only be accessible from processes on the same host as the server is running.

However, when your client is **connecting** to a server, it must specify the actual hostname or IP address it is connecting to, which could be `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` or whatever is the IP address that the server is connected to on the network. However, you cannot use `0.0.0.0` in the connection string from the client to the server, as that's not a valid IP address to connect to.

Comment: I've tried it before with localhost, yields the same result. Since the server is actually running on the same machine this should work. Note, that i can succesfully telnet on the localhost:8182